# Understand the solving strategy for difference equations.

Tags: recurrence-relations, substitution

Suppose we have $y[n+2]=y[n+1]+y[n]$ also known as fib sequence.

Then re-write it like: $y[n+2]-y[n+1]-y[n]= 0$ (Cool this is a homogeneous difference equation)

Now they claim that there exist a $r\in \mathbb R$ so that $y[n]=r^n$ .
I agree with all of this concept but I do not understand why now $y[n+1]=r^n*r$

Actually I do not get how this idea of substitute working. Can someone explain to me??
I found it here: `http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ZTransformDEMod.html`

Comment: Because $y[n+1]=r^{n+1}=r^n r$ by the law of exponents.

Comment: @Bernard I know that. I don't get why $y[n+1] = r^n*r$ if $ y[n]=r^n $

Comment: Why, you substitute $n+1$ to $n$ in the formula. That's a basic fact in logic.